# What is the intuitive meaning of the typical value $e^{\left\langle \log X \right\rangle}$ of a random variable $X$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition, disorder

The notion of the typical value $e^{\left\langle \log X \right\rangle}$ of a random variable $X$ comes up often in the study of disordered systems. For examples see the short paragraph above eq. (4) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08869.pdf) or the caption of Fig. 13 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.05642.pdf). (These papers may not be the best examples, I'll try to find more, if needed.) What is the intuitive meaning of this quantity in general (not restricted to the context of these papers) and how exactly does it differ from studying the average $\langle X \rangle$?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [Why do we disorder-average before/after taking the logarithm of the partition function for annealed/quenched disorder?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/389336/why-do-we-disorder-average-before-after-taking-the-logarithm-of-the-partition-fu)

Answer (score 3):

Without any knowledge in disordered systems, an intuitive answer is that an average of the type $\exp \langle\log X\rangle$, tries to capture the expected order of magntiude of $X$, which is particularly important when fluctuations in the order of magnitude of $X$ are anticipated. If you are familiar with the geometric mean, this is simply a generalization.

If we tried to use $ \langle X\rangle$ for this, we would be overemphasizing the importance of positive order of magnitude fluctuations, and underemphasizing the importance of negative order of magnitude fluctuations. For example the series $X=1/100,1/10,1,10,100$ has mean $\langle X\rangle\approx 22$, but geometric mean $\exp\langle\log X\rangle=1$. Which of those numbers better capture important information about the data?